# Packer Docker Builder with remote docker daemon

Tags: docker, ansible, packer

I'm using packer docker builder with ansible to create docker image (https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html)

I have a machine(client) which is meant to run build scripts. The packer docker is executed with ansible from this machine. This machine has docker client. It's connected to a remote docker daemon. The environment variable DOCKER_HOST is set to point to the remote docker host. I'm able to test the connectivity and things are working good.

Now the problem is, when I execute packer docker to build the image, it errors out saying:

```
   docker: Run command: docker run -v /root/.packer.d/tmp/packer-docker612435850:/packer-files -d -i -t ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
==> docker: Error running container: Docker exited with a non-zero exit status.
==> docker: Stderr: docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
==> docker: See 'docker run --help'.
```

It seems the packer docker is stuck looking at local daemon.

Workaround: I renamed docker binary and introduced a script called "docker" which sets DOCKER_HOST and invokes the original docker binary with parameters passed on.

Is there a better way to deal this?

Comment: Packer does have [Communicators](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/communicator.html) that can be attached to a builder, that might shunt all the docker commands via the ssh connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packers Docker builder doesn't work with remote hosts since packer uses the `/packer-files` volume mount to communicate with the container. This is vaguely expressed in the docs with:

> The Docker builder must run on a machine that has Docker installed.

And explained in [Overriding the host directory](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html#overriding-the-host-directory).

Comment: I did a small update of the docs to clarify this, see https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/pull/5992/files It will be deployed with the next release.